# What am I doing wrong? Gram Schmidt process..

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, definite-integrals, inner-products, orthonormal

Let there be the inner product of all polynomials of degree smaller or equal to 2: $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)xdx$. Find orthonormal basis.

So I really tried this for an hour and it pretty much became annoying, as I can't tell what's my mistake. Let $E=\{1,x,x^2\}$ be the standard basis.

$u_1=1$

$u_2=x-\langle x,1\rangle1=x-\int_0^1x\cdot1\cdot x dx=x-\int_0^1x^2dx=x-\frac{1}{3}$

There is also $u_3$ but let's say I can find it successfully. Lets find the normal of $u_1$ and $u_2$:

$\|u_1\|=\sqrt{\int_0^11\cdot1 \cdot x dx}=\sqrt{\int_0^1x dx}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \rightarrow \hat u_1=\sqrt2$

$\|u_2\|=\sqrt{\int_0^1(x-\frac{1}{3})^2\cdot x dx}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{12}} \rightarrow \hat u_2=\sqrt{12}(x-\frac{1}{3})$

But $\langle u_1,u_2\rangle=\int_0^1\sqrt2 \cdot \sqrt{12}(x-\frac{1}{3})\cdot x dx \neq 0$.

What's my mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user89987 He's integrating $x^2$..

Comment: @mathematician Oops, missed the $x$ in the definition of the inner product. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake is when you put

$$
u_2 = x - \langle x , 1 \rangle \cdot 1 \ .
$$

You indeed have that the second vector is something like

$$
u_2 = v_2 + \lambda v_1 \ ,
$$

where $v_1, v_2$ are the first vectors of your original basis. Now you want to replace them by $u_1, u_2$ being orthogonal. So you set $u_1 = v_1$ and impose

$$
0 = \langle u_1, u_2\rangle = \langle v_1, v_2 + \lambda v_1\rangle = \langle v_1, v_2\rangle + \lambda \langle v_1, v_1\rangle \ .
$$

Which entails that you must take

$$
\lambda = - \frac{\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle}{\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle} \ .
$$

That is,

$$
u_2 = x - \frac{\langle 1, x \rangle}{\langle 1, 1 \rangle} \cdot 1 \ .
$$

would be better.

Comment: I see. For some reason I was taught otherwise. Much gratitude!!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define $u_2$ as x-sqrt(2) or something then normalize $u_2$.  You just want to subtract the component of x along $u_1$ from x, but you are doing more than this because $u_1$ doesn't have length 1.